# Proving a basis generates a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given the following problem (this is actually homework, however, it seems like the tag is deprecated). Let $X \neq \phi$, $K$ be a field, then $K^X = \{f : X \to K\}$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $K$. Determine a generating set of $K^X$ when $X$ is finite.

So far, I have realized that $\#X< \infty$  implies that X can be put in bijection with some subset of $\mathbb{N}$, hence, there exists a "$\#X$-tuple" such that the $i$-th component is $f(x)$, where $x$ is the $i$-th element of $X$. I expressed this by saying that there exists a sequence $I_n \subset X$ such that $1 \leq n \leq \#X$ and $I_n$ is bijective, then I define $f_i(x) = 1$ if $x = I_i$, $0$ otherwise.

With these definitions, its very easy to reach a contradiction when supposing that vectors in $M = \{f_i : i \in \mathbb{N} / 1 \leq i \leq \#X\}$ are not linearly independent.

Since I want to prove that $M$ is a basis for $K^X$, I also need to prove that $M$ generates $K^X$. I tried doing this by induction over $\#X$: since I can put all sets of $\#X$ elements in bijection between themselves, it is the same to prove it over any set of $\#X$ elements. However, my proof is at best hand-wavy, and it seems like its the wrong way to approach the problem.

I'd like some other ideas about how to prove this, as well as possible insight into how to write these ideas with more formalism.

Comment: Let $f_x(y) = \begin{cases} 1_K & y=x \\ 0_K & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$, where $1_K$ is the multiplicative identity of $K$ and $0_K$ is the additive identity of $K$. Now try to represent any member of $K^X$ as a $K$-linear combination of the $f_x$.